# Click link that is in <td>

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple table:

```
 <tr>
   <td>
    <a href="/patients/5"> … </a>
   </td>
   ....
```

Im trying to trigger the link in a when a user clicks on tr:
So I wrote this code:

```
<script>
 $("tr").click(function(){
  this.next("a").click();
 })
</script>
```

First i got this error:

```
Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'next'
```

next i tried:

```
<script>
 $("tr").click(function(){
  this.siblings().click();
 })
</script>
```

But then i get this error:

```
 Object #<HTMLTableRowElement> has no method 'siblings'
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: the anchor tag is not the next element, and it is not a sibling of the tr. it is a **child** of the tr. Also, `this` is a dom node, not a jQuery object, therefore it has no .siblings method.

Comment: wrap your `this` with jQuery so you can actually use `.next()`.... i.e. `$(this).next`...

Comment: Can someone please post a good answer? With Krishnas anwer i get an error: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).find("a")[0].click()` this will trigger it.

The below trigger the click handler for this link.

```
$("tr").click(function(){
  $(this).find("a").first().trigger('click');
})
```

***[jsFIddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96VRL/1/)***

Comment: Might want to add that this will trigger the handler for the link element, not the native click function.

Comment: `$(this).find("a")[0].click()` however would trigger it, fyi.

Comment: Now i get this error : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: If there are more than 1 link, use `$(this).find("a")[0]` to trigger the first one.

Comment: Next error: [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'trigger'

Comment: wrap it with `$($(this).find("a")[0])`.. this will convert HTMLElement to jquery selector.

Comment: Now i have the old error again `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @JohnSmith Unless we see your full code, there is no way we can solve this comprehensively, it looks like you're running into an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: @JohnSmith try writing `e.stopPropagation()` in your click handler. Added my demo in the answer. open your console in your chrome to see the result.